# Finding the Previous Sibling Element in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

While writing some code I came across two ways of doing the same thing. I am looking for the most efficient way to find a previous sibling, in order to extract a string from it.

My project does currently use jQuery, so both options are available to me.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/previousSibling

http://api.jquery.com/prev/

What is the better option to use and why?

Comment: Both have their pros and cons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can do it in [Vanilla JavaScript](http://vanilla-js.com/), then do so.

jQuery will always be slower, because it runs through a lot of function calls and abstraction layers - these layers make it (supposedly*) much easier to write code, but the browser has to do significantly more work for the same effect.

<sub>* Maybe I've been doing Vanilla JavaScript for too long, but I find jQuery horrible to use personally...</sub>

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to be working with it as a jQuery object after fetching it, use jQuery. Otherwise it's pretty expensive to reconvert it to a jQuery object. If you're only going to be using [Vanilla JS](http://vanilla-js.com/), use the plain DOM methods.

Answer (score 1):

`previousSibling` is a native property so obviously that will be faster but it's read-only, you can use it only to read properties of previous node. But it's not supported in IE8 or below, so you'll have to resort to `previousElementSibling` in those browsers which also gives read-only access to previous node.

If you are going to wrap the returning node in jQuery again, I suggest you use `prev` as it abstracts all these browser differences and also returns a jQuery object. So there's a little overhead for this.

Answer (score 0):

Jquery internally uses previousSibling  method only, so it would be little slower than the native method(i.e previousSibling ). Only thing is both return different results, previousSibling  returns a node and prev will return jquery wrapper element for same node.